# XMLSerialization and XML Schema validation

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xsd

Is it possible to use the XML Schema validation and XMLSerializer together?

My project currently uses XMLSerializer. To validate the schema, we are programatically checking the values like:

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(person.Name))
   throw new Exception();
```

Thanks!

Comment: is the 'validation' information present in the schema? Or is the xml being checked against rules that are not in the schema?

Comment: Similar question: [schema validation XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584080/schema-validation-xml/4639448#4639448)

Comment: @Devendra: Currently, the validations rules are implemented in code. But if it is possible to use XML schema validation, the validation information will be placed on an XSD file.

Comment: it is possible to perform some validation in the xml schema. There are attributes like default, nillable, fixed, etc. that allow basic validation. More complex rules are to be implemented in code.

Comment: An alternative to writing the rules in code, they can be written in xml and then used by the code to validate the xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the XmlValidatingReader for validatiing the schema. Please see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/Serialization.aspx for an example...

Comment: The XMLValidatingReader was deprecated in .NET 2.0  

The XmlValidatingReader class is obsolete in Microsoft .NET Framework version 2.0. You can create a validating XmlReader instance by using the XmlReaderSettings class and the Create method. For more information, see Validating XML Data with XmlReader.

Answer (score 2):

You can add some additional checking to the xsd, by using the element restriction element. Each type have some facets that you can apply to the type/element - ranging from simple min/max length to regular expressions.

You can even take it one step further and use the appinfo xsd element, where you can add custom specification for etc. validation checking. This step however require you to parse each xml node individually, as the normal Xml Schema Validation don't trigger appinfo functionality.

As a last resort you can even have a look at Schematron, which is a formalized way to add quite complex validation to your xsd, but it is in itself a bit complex, and in many situations overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can just provide an XSD within the XML. When you read it using the XMLSerializer, it will throw exceptions if the XML is not matching the XSD.