# How to know which xml file failed validation

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd

I have this code to validate my xml :

```
private bool ValidateXML(string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        XmlDocument xmld = new XmlDocument();
        xmld.Load(filePath);
        xmld.Schemas.Add(null, @"C:\...\....xsd");
        xmld.Validate(ValidationEventHandler);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}

static void ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Severity)
    {
        case XmlSeverityType.Error:
            Debug.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);
            break;
        case XmlSeverityType.Warning:
            Debug.WriteLine("Warning {0}", e.Message);
            break;
    }
}
```

But when I am in the call back how do I know the filePath of the failed file? I would like to move it to a "Failed" folder but without knowing which one it is I cannot.

Comment: What type is the `sender` object? Maybe you can retrieve some information from there...

Comment: Maybe rather use this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584080/schema-validation-xml

Comment: @marsze thanks your comment solved the issue, all I needed was to throw an error in the callback method.

Answer (score 0):

instead of returning a bool you could return the filepath if it failed, and an empty string if it passed.  Or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an anonymous method so that your "file" variable can get "captured" so you can use it inside the `ValidationEvent` callback.

```
    public static bool ValidateXmlFile1(string filePath, XmlSchemaSet set)
    {
        bool bValidated = true;

        try
        {
            XmlDocument tmpDoc = new XmlDocument();

            tmpDoc.Load(filePath);

            tmpDoc.Schemas = set;

            ValidationEventHandler eventHandler = new ValidationEventHandler(
                (Object sender, ValidationEventArgs e) =>
                {
                    switch (e.Severity)
                    {
                        case XmlSeverityType.Error:
                            {
                                Debug.WriteLine("Error: {0} on file [{1}]", e.Message, filePath);

                            } break;

                        case XmlSeverityType.Warning:
                            {
                                Debug.WriteLine("Error: {0} on file [{1}]", e.Message, filePath);

                            } break;
                    }

                    bValidated = false;
                }
            );

            tmpDoc.Validate(eventHandler);
        }
        catch
        {
            bValidated = false;
        }

        return bValidated;
    }
```